# The icons of various apps in the ISO file

Tags: icons, 20.04, ubiquity

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 two days back. I instantly fell in love with the ***Install Ubuntu*** icon at the desktop while installing.

Where can I get it from the ISO file or forums for using somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file browser and go to the location

```
/usr/share/icons
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open the search bar.

Insert the word "ubiquity" and you will have a list of all the icons (png and svg) available.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the file from the iso, you could mount the iso, then within that, mount /casper/filesystem.squashfs, then, as suggested by @schrodigerscatcuriosity, search for ubiquity within /usr/share/icons

Suppose you have the iso file in your Downloads directory:

```
# make two directories to mount into
mkdir ~/mnt-iso ~/mnt-squash

# mount the iso file
mount ~/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso ~/mnt-iso

# mount squashfs file
mount -t squashfs ~/mnt-iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs ~/mnt-squash

# search for ubiquity icons
find ~/mnt-squash/usr/share/icons/ -name ubiquity.*
```

The final find command could be replaced by the search procedure suggested by @schrodigerscatcuriosity.  In that case, you would search within ~/mnt-squash/usr/share/icons

When you are done, unmount the files in reverse order:

```
umount ~/mnt-squash
umount ~/mnt-iso
```